# Regular Expression (notepad++) insert, not replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

In a regular expression (notepad++), I want to search for:`( )|(:)|(_)|(\.)`, and to insert `\` before to, as above, a blank space, colon, under line and ".".

Search example: `abcd:1234 jiod.8ufd_adfd`

Result: `abcd\:1234\ jiod\.8ufd\_adfd`

Briefly, how can I refer to what was found in the replace expression?

Note that it is not `\1, \2, \3 or \4` in the example, as I need to include what was found, there is no way to know which was found, is there?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a backslash before each colon, space dot or underscore? match `[:\h._]` and replace with a backslash and the full match `\\$&` https://regex101.com/r/Si6rHp/1

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single character class (instead of using the alternation with capturing groups) to match one of the listed

In the replacement use  `$&` to refer to the matched text and prepend a backslash.

Match

```
[:\h._]
```

Replace with

```
\\$&
```

The character class matches either a colon, horizontal whitespace char, dot or underscore.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Si6rHp/1/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as insert, because if you think about it, inserting is just replacing the original with a new string that contains the old text as well.

Try this instead: search for `([ :_.])` (your original regex is pointlessly complicated) and replace with `\\$1` (ie, slash followed by the original text).